# Is there a Yesod alternative to the Rails' `link_to foo, bar, method: "delete"?

Tags: haskell, yesod

Is there a simple way to generate a link that uses a different method than `GET` in Yesod, such as in Ruby on Rails, where one can do `link_to foo, bar, method: "post"`, which would submit the link via JavaScript?

**update:** What Ruby on Rails does is that it generates a `data-method` attribute, which is then handled by its own JavaScript library. I'm not necessarily looking for exactly the same solution, but rather if there is an existing mechanism for creating `POST` links in Yesod.

Comment: You should probably add your expected result, as some might know Yesod but not Rails (e.g. `<a href="bar" rel="nofollow" data-method="post">foo</a>`).

Comment: @Zeta This also assumes that Yesod does anything with this. `data-method` by itself doesn't do anything.

Comment: Note that links with non-`GET` methods require Javascript on the client side, see e.g. http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to "Note that if the user has JavaScript disabled, the request will fall back to using `GET`."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an implementation of roughly what Rails is doing. This involves several parts: generating the link, using Javascript to implement the method changing functionality, and extra code for CSRF protection on the backend. Here's the linking aspect:

```
linkToPost :: Route App -> [(Text,Text)] -> Text -> Widget
linkToPost = linkToMethod "POST"

linkToMethod :: Text -> Route App -> [(Text,Text)] -> Text -> Widget
linkToMethod method url attributes content = 
    toWidget [hamlet|
    $newline never
    <a href="@{url}" rel="nofollow" data-method="#{method}" *{attributes}>#{content}</a>
    |]
```

Which you can use like so:

```
^{linkToPost CommentR [] "Create comment"}
```

At this point, Javascript is required to handle the `data-method` attribute. You can actually just include [`rails.js`](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js) and the above code will work fine. At the cost of considerable pain to myself and many runtime errors, I've extracted the relevant Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on("click", "a[data-method]", function() {
    var link = $(this);
    var method = link.data('method');

    handleMethod(link);
    return false;
  });
});

function handleMethod(link) {
  var href = link.attr('href'),
    method = link.data('method'),
    csrfToken = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content'),
    form = $('<form method="POST" action="' + href + '"></form>'),
    metadataInput = '<input name="_method" value="' + method + '" type="hidden" />';

  if (csrfToken !== undefined) {
    metadataInput += '<input name="_token" value="' + csrfToken + '" type="hidden" />';
  }

  form.hide().append(metadataInput).appendTo('body');

  form.submit();
}
```

Note that if the form has a method of type POST and a `_method` parameter, Yesod's default [middleware](https://github.com/yesodweb/wai/blob/07688c086ad26ea91b1009bb58cdb5cbae7c8e9b/wai-extra/Network/Wai/Middleware/MethodOverridePost.hs) will override the method to the value of `_method`, just like Rails. The above Javascript is assuming this is enabled.

To take advantage of the CSRF protection that Rails.js is using, we need to embed the CSRF token into our page's `<head>`. First, I grab the CSRF token in the `defaultLayout` function:

```
mCsrfToken <- fmap reqToken getRequest
```

Then embed it into the page header inside `default-layout-wrapper.hamlet`:

```
$maybe token <- mCsrfToken
  <meta name="csrf-token" content=#{token}>
```

At this point, the normal CSRF protection used for forms can be applied. It's getting late for me, but I came up with this as a way for simple requests (like DELETE /users/1) to check the CSRF token, there might be a better way than this:

```
checkCsrf :: Handler ()
checkCsrf = do
    ((res, _), _) <- runFormPost (renderDivs (mempty :: AForm Handler () ))
    case res of
        FormSuccess _ -> return ()
        _ -> permissionDenied "CSRF failure"
```

This was a long answer + I'm getting tired, so code review on the above is welcome.

### Update

Now that Yesod has support for [embedding CSRF tokens in cookies](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-5.9/yesod-core-1.4.19/Yesod-Core-Handler.html#g:28), and validating them in request headers, you probably want to use that rather than embed the token in the HTML and making your request a form. Reasoning:

- Looking up a value from a cookie is simpler and better supported than an HTML query.
- Adding a request header is compatible with POSTing JSON/binary data, etc. It seems far less hacky to me.
- All this is explicitly supported by tested by Yesod

Comment: Thanks for this! Just one note though, the JavaScript has to send the `_method` param in the query string, not in the body, otherwise the Wai middleware won't pick it up.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a simple way to generate a link that uses a different method than GET in Yesod

Not that I'm aware of.

> an existing mechanism for creating POST links in Yesod

To generate `POST` links specifically, you could render a form styled to look like a link. You could probably wrap this up in a `postLink :: Route -> Widget` helper.